# Check for .NET 4.5.2 in WiX

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, installation

I'm trying to make use of the [WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html) property. I've read the [How-To](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html). Specifically, I have:

- Added a reference to WixNetFxExtension.dll (located at **`C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.9\bin\\WixNetFxExtension.dll`**)
- Added **`xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"`** to my **`<Wix>`** tag.
- Referenced my property: **`<PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"/>`**

But I get the following error when I try to compile:

> Error 8   Unresolved reference to symbol
>   'Property:WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED' in section
>   'Product:*'.  C:\Code\Installer\Product.wxs   46  1   WiXInstaller

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

**Edit**: I don't see any references to WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED in the 3.9 source code, so why is it in the documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those properties are new to WiX v3.10.

Comment: Well, that answers it. Thanks.

Comment: This answer explains why it doesn't work but unfortunately I'm still in the dark about how to do it. Upgrading to WiX v3.10 seems to cause all sorts of other issues.